# bash script skips create database creation

Tags: linux, bash

This function should configure mariadb (with pw) and after a successfull configuration it should move forward to create a database, but it seems to skip the command.

Code snippet:

```
if [ $configure_sql = 1 ]
then
    echo -e "${RED}Achtung:${CYAN} Es wird nun die Datebank konfiguriert, breche diesen Prozess nicht ab."
    secureinstall=$(expect -c "

        spawn mysql_secure_installation

        expect \"Enter current password for root (enter for none): \"
        send \"n\r\"
        expect \"Change the root password? \[Y/n\] \"
        send \"y\r\"
        expect \"New password: \"
        send \"securepw\r\"
        expect \"Re-enter new password: \"
        send \"securepw\r\"
        expect \"Remove anonymous users? \[Y/n\] \"
        send \"y\r\"
        expect \"Disallow root login remotely? \[Y/n\] \"
        send \"y\r\"
        expect \"Remove test database and access to it? \[Y/n\] \"
        send \"y\r\"
        expect \"Reload privilege tables now? \[Y/n\] \"
        send \"y\r\"
        expect eof
        ")
    echo "$secureinstall"
    echo -e "\033[35mErstellen der Datenbank.\033[0m"
    sleep 5
    createdb=$( mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE testdb;" )
    echo "$createdb"
    echo -e "\033[35mNun wird die Datenbank mit Sysbench Test Content gefüllt!\033[0m"
    sleep 5

    mysql_prepare=$( mysql_prepare )
    echo "$mysql_prepare"
    echo -e "\033[35mAlles erledigt, weiter gehts!\033[0m"
    sleep 5
    clear
fi
```

**Log of bash -x:**

```
Erstellen der Datenbank.
+ sleep 5
++ mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE testdb;'
++ sysbench oltp_read_write --db-driver=mysql --table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=testdb --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=securepw --time=60 --max-requests=0 --num-threads=1 run
++ grep queries:
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ createdb=
+ echo ''
```

*if it helps I can provide the whole script.*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and also show the output you would expect. Which command seems to be skipped? Is the problem that you don't see `"${RED}Achtung:${CYAN} Es wird nun die Datebank konfiguriert, breche diesen Prozess nicht ab."` being printed? The output contains lines that don't match the code snippet. I suggest to simplify your script to find the problem, see [mre].

Comment: @NothingTV : But your log explicitly shows that CREATE DATABASE **is** executed: Accrding to the log, it does a `mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE testdb'`. What happens when you manually run the command? I find it odd that it does not seem to produce an output to stdout or stderr. Are you sure that `mysql` **really** runs maria-db in your script, and not some shell script of the same name, which comes earlier in the PATH? Do y `type mysql` in your code.

Comment: @user1934428 when I run the command manually it creates the database, usually it should show that its already created. So thats the point where I think it doesnt really runs the command and only prints it
I just created a minified version just with creating the db, so usually it would work, but it seems to skip it.. I dont get it, I can link the full script if it helps.

Comment: That's why I suggested to verify using `type` that you get the correct command in the script too.....  I would also do a `mysql -V` right before creating the database. If this does not show your mysql version number, you can be pretty sure that a different command is run here which just happens to have the same name. Also, for completeness: Since you catch the stdout from `mysql` into a variable, is there a reason why you don't catch the stderr too?

Comment: @user1934428 I'm kinda new to bash, so error catching is completely new for me. I dont even know where to start. And this problem is kinda unsolveable for me. I tried several things in the last few hours..

Comment: Aside from the commands I already told you in the comments above, you catch the error output by `createdb=$( mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE testdb;" 2>&1)`. This works with every command which outputs to stderr.

Comment: good lord.. I had a function with the name ```mysql``` no wonder why it cant run the actual mysql command.. Sorry for wasting your and my time..